# Android(Kotlin) Toast using Elvis Operator to use a Default String value when value from intent/arguments is Null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, arguments, toast

I have this kind of implementation

```
Toast.makeText(activity,arguments?.get("message") as String, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

So, the thing is I want to make the use of **Elvis Operator(?:)** here, so as to use some **default** String, when the value to show inside toast is Null.
I could not implement it properly. So, How do I implement it in the **same line of code** ??.
Also, what will be the better way to do it ??
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put elvis operator after the nullable get call:

```kotlin
Toast.makeText(activity, arguments?.get("message") ?: "Default value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Here's some observations:

- `null ?: "default"` evaluates to `default`
- `"valid str" ?: "default"` evaluates to `valid str`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
Toast.makeText(activity, arguments?.get("message") ?: "default message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score -3):

Probably something like this

```
Toast.makeText(activity,arguments!!.get("message") ?: "default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

When `?` is used it just ignores the null, but on `!!` one has to handle the fallback.

Comment: This will actually cause a `KotlinNullPointerException` to be thrown at runtime if `arguments` is `null`, so the Elvis operator won't be called. And if `arguments` is not null, then the Elvis operator won't be executed either.

Comment: @user2340612 +1, but wanna add that if `get("message")` might be null, then elvis is going to be executed.

Comment: @user2340612 it will be called if there are arguments, but no value with that key. But still, this is a bad solution, which can lead to an NPE for no reason

Comment: well that's true if `arguments` is a `Map` (which seems likely), otherwise it depends on its actual type. But thank you both for pointing that out, it's a good observation!